# How to continue reading the data from the console and save to file using BufferedReader?

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I want to make a small program in which user can able to write the entire file through the console. Here I'm facing the issue, and is that I'm using BufferedReader using this I can able to read the data from console but if I press the enter button then it  won't read and program will end.
So how to continue reading the data  from the console even if user press the enter button.
And please also suggest the right way to end the file writing process.

Before using the BufferedReader I was using Scanner but there also facing some issues. After that I've tried out this one but don't know how to read all the lines?

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        System.out.println("When you press ctrl+z your file writing process will be end.");
        System.out.println("Now press enter to write a file...");
        s.nextLine();
        String fileStr = null;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while((fileStr = reader.readLine()) != null){
            byte[] data = fileStr.getBytes();
            fos.write(data);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        s.close();
        if(fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the code you already have

Answer (score 0):

Hou are very close, I think you should loop on s.nextLine() like that :

```
package com.company;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String RETURN = "\n";
        Path filePath = Paths.get("fileName");

        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            if (!Files.exists(filePath)) {
                Files.createFile(filePath);
            }
            System.out.println("When you press ctrl+z your file writing process will be end.");
            System.out.println("Now press enter to write a file...");
            s.nextLine();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String fileStr = "";
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(!reader.readLine().equals("")) { // reader.readline() will return null if no caracter to read (last line of file)
                fileStr = fileStr + line + RETURN; // Read next line before looping and \n append return
                byte[] data = fileStr.getBytes();
                Files.write(filePath, data, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gweltaz Niquel. I've tried out your way, but data which is written in the new line or after pressing the enter button can't be store into file.

Comment: @MilanBhatt Try using ```fos.flush()```, see if that works, an alternative is using ```DataInputStream``` with ```readUTF()```. I haven't tried it but I think that might work

Answer (score 0):

You should

1. Use try-with-resources on streams, so java itself handels closing the streams in every case
2. Dont use FileInputStream, java has an nice API for files in NIO e.g. `Files.write(Path, Iterable<? extends CharSequence>)`, where you can either write the whole File at once, or just append to the File.
3. Dont close Scanner connected to `System.in`, this will also close the underlying stream (so `System.in`)
4. You have currently no way of breaking the while-loop, it will always wait for user-Input, the interrupt wont reach into the Loop, so you need to implement some way to exit

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    private static final String DOCUMENT_END_TOKEN = ">e";
    
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
            try {
                    System.out.println("When you type '>e' your file writing process will be terminated.");
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    System.out.println("File name?");
                    String fileName = reader.readLine();
                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                    System.out.println("Now write to the file: " + fileName);
                    StringBuilder fileContentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String readDocLine = reader.readLine();
                    while (!readDocLine.equalsIgnoreCase(DOCUMENT_END_TOKEN)) {
                            fileContentBuilder.append(readDocLine).append("\n");
                            readDocLine = reader.readLine();
                    }
                    byte[] data = fileContentBuilder.toString().getBytes();
                    fileOutputStream.write(data);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                    s.close();
            }
    }
```